# SQL Finding five largest numbers instead of one Max in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table and I need to run a query that contains some aggregation Functions like Maximum , Average , Standard Deviation , ...
but instead of one Maximum I should return 5 largest number.

the simplified query is something like this:

```
SELECT OSI_KEY , MAX(VALUE) , AVG(VALUE) , STDDEV(VALUE), variance(VALUE) 
FROM DATA_VALUES_5MIN_6_2013
GROUP BY OSI_KEY
ORDER BY OSI_KEY
```

and I need some Magical ;) Query like this:

```
    SELECT OSI_KEY , MAX1(VALUE) ,MAX2(VALUE) ,MAX3(VALUE) ,MAX4(VALUE) , MAX5(VALUE) ,
    AVG(VALUE) , STDDEV(VALUE), variance(VALUE) 
    FROM DATA_VALUES_5MIN_6_2013
    GROUP BY OSI_KEY
    ORDER BY OSI_KEY
```

I appreciate your considerations.

Comment: you can try "Select Top 5 ..." followed by your query after order by value decending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has an `NTH_VALUE()` function.  Unfortunately, it is only an analytic function and not a window function.  This leads to the strange construct of `SELECT DISTINCT` with a bunch of analytic functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OSI_KEY,
       MAX(VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY OSI_KEY),
       NTH_VALUE(VALUE, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY OSI_KEY ORDER BY VALUE DESC) as MAX_2,
       NTH_VALUE(VALUE, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY OSI_KEY ORDER BY VALUE DESC) as MAX_3,
       NTH_VALUE(VALUE, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY OSI_KEY ORDER BY VALUE DESC) as MAX_4,
       NTH_VALUE(VALUE, 5) OVER (PARTITION BY OSI_KEY ORDER BY VALUE DESC) as MAX_5,
       AVG(VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY OSI_KEY),
       STDDEV(VALUE)  OVER (PARTITION BY OSI_KEY),
       variance(VALUE)  OVER (PARTITION BY OSI_KEY)
FROM DATA_VALUES_5MIN_6_2013
ORDER BY OSI_KEY;
```

You can also do this using conditional aggregation, with a `row_number()` or `dense_rank()` in a subquery.

Comment: isn't the name of function  `NTH_VALUE`?

Comment: Thank you @RadimBača it was very help full. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OSI_KEY, MaxValue FROM (
    SELECT OSI_KEY, MAX(value) AS MaxValue FROM table GROUP BY OSI_KEY
)
ORDER BY MaxValue DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: How to combine with GROUP BY OSI_KEY?

Comment: Thank you Lamar, But your query just returns the five largest numbers in five records, But what I need is five maximum beside each other and beside them other agrigation functions (AVG , Variance , ... ).